# Change text using SpannableStringBuilder

Tags: java, android, regex, string, spannablestringbuilder

I want to make text when surrounded by (*) it will be bold and surrounded by (~) it will be strike. I following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40008579/6310518) and modify the code to be like this

```
text = "*~TEST~* *TEST* ~TEST~ TEST";
texview.setText(createSpannable(text))

private static SpannableStringBuilder createSpannable(final String str) {
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

        //Matcher matcher = BOLD_REGEX.matcher(str);
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\*(.*?)\\*)|(~(.*?)~)").matcher(str); //BOLD | STRIKE
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String group = matcher.group();

            stringBuffer.setLength(0);


            if (BOLD_REGEX.matcher(group).matches()) {//(\*(.*?)\*)
                String spanText = group.substring(1, group.length() - 1);
                matcher.appendReplacement(stringBuffer, spanText);
                spannableStringBuilder.append(stringBuffer.toString());
                int start = spannableStringBuilder.length() - spanText.length();
                spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(new StyleSpan(BOLD), start, spannableStringBuilder.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

                if (STRIKE_REGEX.matcher(spannableStringBuilder).matches()) {
                    createSpannable(spannableStringBuilder.toString());
                }
            }

            if (STRIKE_REGEX.matcher(group).matches()) {//(~(.*?)~)
                String spanText1 = group.substring(1, group.length() - 1);
                matcher.appendReplacement(stringBuffer, spanText1);
                spannableStringBuilder.append(stringBuffer.toString());
                int start1 = spannableStringBuilder.length() - spanText1.length();
                spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), start1, spannableStringBuilder.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

                if (BOLD_REGEX.matcher(spannableStringBuilder).matches()) {
                    createSpannable(spannableStringBuilder.toString());
                }
            }
        }

        stringBuffer.setLength(0);
        matcher.appendTail(stringBuffer);
        spannableStringBuilder.append(stringBuffer.toString());

        return spannableStringBuilder;
    }
```

Expectation Output :

[image: Expectation]

My Output :

[image: My Output]

How can i achieve this?

Comment: You are processing a string with one pass, but your matches are overlapping. Split this replacement logic into two steps, one with `\*([^*]*)\*` regex and the other with `~([^~]*)~`

Comment: Try like this: `text = "~*TEST*~ *TEST* ~TEST~ TEST";`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i have change my regex with yours , but the result remain the same

Comment: I did not recommend to change the regex, I suggest to split the programming logic to run subsitutions twice, to process a string twice, once with the first regex and then with the second.

Comment: @Ümañgßürmån i think that doesn't help, because the text is dynamic